# Какой display у элемента со свойством float?

Tags: html, css, float

**Интересен следующий момент:**

Много где пишут что мол если элементу присваивается свойство `float:left;` или `float:right;` то `display` будет иметь значение `block`!

Но я не соглашусь!

Пример:

```css
.a
{
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
}
.b
{
  width:100px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">This is Photoshop 1.</div>
<div class="b">This is Photoshop 2.</div>
```

**Результат:** Один блок будет в ряду с другим.

Но это возможно когда стоит `inline-block` у обоих элементов. Иначе бы на одной строке нельзя было бы расположить 2 блока т.к всю ширину занимал бы блок с `display:block;`.

Вот еще пример:

```css
.a
{
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
  opacity:0.7;
  padding:5px;
}
.b
{
  background:red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">This is Photoshop 1.</div>
<div class="b">This is Photoshop 2.</div>
```

**Результат:** один блок в ряду с другим, но за той лишь разницей что флоатный элемент игнорируется и блок занимает место под ним. Хотя текст находится вне первого блока

В инспекторе кода элемент с `float:left;` показывает `display:block;`...опять же не понятно! Свою точку зрения я описал. Объясните мне если что-то я не так понял.

P.S Кто не понял вопроса!

Почему элемент cо свойством-значением `display:inline-block;`, который стоит после элемента со свойством-значением `float:left;` находится на одной строке?(Если провести тоже самое но без `float:left;` то элементы не будут находится на одной строке т.к `display:block;` заберет всю ширину).

Comment: `float` никак не связан с `display`. У тебя оказывается display:block, потому что это стандартное значение этого свойства для элемента div

Comment: @Grundy На многих ресурсах упоминается что display будет равен block. Вот я интересуюсь. Так все равно ведь должен же быть какой-нибудь тип display?

Comment: @Grundy чудесно, но не объясняет почему желтый блок в примере ведет себя как `inline-block`.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, потому что на самом деле он ведет себя не как _inline-block_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy а как он себя ведет по вашему?

Comment: @Grundy Именно как inline-block, что вообще удивительно почему все пишут про block

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, как _float_ - это же очевидно

Comment: @Grundy не такого значения у `display` - `float`. Вы вопрос-то поняли?

Comment: Если они ведут себя как inline-block так примените к ним vertical-align

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, а где я говорил, что _значения у display - float_? :-)

Comment: @Grundy мы обсуждаем значение свойства `display` у элемента, которому задано еще и `float: left`. У вас есть ответ, почему такой блок ведет себя как `display: inline-block`, хотя в инспекторе у него `display: block`?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, так я ж написал - он не ведет себя как _inline block_.

Comment: @Grundy ладно, пусть не ведет, но очень похоже что ведет. ) Почему ширина блока меняется когда задаешь `float`?

Answer (score 1):

`float` действительно влияет на вычисленное значение свойства `display`, на MDN можно найти таблицу, которая предоставляет [полный список](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) изменений.

---

*Но это возможно когда стоит inline-block у обоих элементов. Иначе бы на одной строке нельзя было бы расположить 2 блока т.к всю ширину занимал бы блок с display:block;.*

Начнем с контр-примера:

```css
p {
  margin: 5px;
}

.floats {
  float:left;
  background: #ccc;
}

.dib {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class=dib>1. Something</p>
<p class=floats>2. Something</p>
<p class=floats>3. Something</p>
```

Очевидно, что если бы флоаты вели себя так же, как и инлайн-блоки, то порядок элементов был бы 1, 2, 3, а не 2, 3, 1. Если вас сбивает с толку *возможность расположения в одной строке*, то это не более, чем визуальный эффект :-) `float` так устроен по спецификации, что элемент, который обладает этим свойством изымается из потока и всплывает слева или справа, а *контент* остальных блоков его *обтекает*.

Единственная, на мой взгляд, схожесть инлайн-блока и флоата состоит в том, что они занимают ту ширину, которую занимает их внутренний контент.

Резюмирую: *Почему элемент cо свойством-значением display:inline-block;, который стоит после элемента со свойством-значением float:left; находится на одной строке?*

Потому что в приведенном вами примере флоат-элемент (1) теряет свою способность занимать 100% доступной ширины и начинает занимать ширину своего контента; (1) и инлайн-блочный (2) занимают достаточно малую ширину, чтобы уместиться на одной строке. Также, при этом они находятся в одном блочном контексте форматирования. Если (2) будет содержать, например, большой параграф текста, то он целиком перенесется на следующую строку, т. е. не будет обтекать (1).

Рекомендую [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting), в которой есть множество примеров и, наверняка, более правильное и доступное описание текущего поведения.

Comment: Я кстати, поэкспериментировал: позадавал флоатным элементам строковые, блочные, строково-блочные отображения и как итог нулевая реакция. Помимо этого я писал флоаты для html тегов, которые по умолчанию имеют режим отображения флоат, как итог в инспекторе кода я не обнаружил стандартный режим отображения (скорее всего это подразумевается инлайновый вид, хотя для тегов с дефолтным отображением блок инспектор показывает блок)

Comment: Вообще удивительно что не сделали режим отображения `display:float-right/left;` Это было бы более логично на мой взгляд ибо дисплэй в сочетании с флоатом не реагирует ну просто никак (возможно какие-то значения дисплэй я просто не заметил).

Comment: Кстати в спецификации которую вы скинули я нашел то что там написано что это является display:block;
*`left
The element generates a` **`block box`** `that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top (subject to the 'clear' property).`*

Comment: В итоге даже спецификация считает что это блочный элемент, но не объясняет почему, возможно я не дошел до того момента

Answer (score -3):

Это справедливо в некоторых случаях. Например, если поставить так:

```
.a {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
```

То результирующее свойство будет `display: block;`.Даже последовательность не важна:

```
.a {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
}
```

все равно, `display: block;`.

Это надо учитывать, когда ведется табличная верстка с помощью `display: table;` и `display: table-cell;`. Элементам надо ставить `float: none;`.

Comment: а кто минус-то влепил? потрудитесь дать коммент или потрудитесь увидеть то, о чем я сказал в инспекторе браузера.

Comment: Может быть потому что ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: Да это не отвечает на вопроc (но минус не я ставил)

Comment: @AndreyFedorov "Много где пишут что мол если элементу присваивается свойство float:left; или float:right; то display будет иметь значение block!" - я показываю случай, где так происходит. А еще - а где вопрос в тексте вопроса?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov когда вопрос не сформулирован, считать ответ любого качества не отвечающим на вопрос - по меньшей мере нелогично.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а логично отвечать на не заданный вопрос? ) пишите коменты, как все. )))

Comment: Логично отвечать на то, как понял вопрос. И в комментах не вставить тот код, что я привел.

Comment: @KAGGDesign `Логично отвечать на то, как понял вопрос` ...............`А еще - а где вопрос в тексте вопроса?` .............  так вы всё же не увидели вопрос или отвечали на какой-то собой придуманный вопрос?))

Comment: "Много где пишут что мол если элементу присваивается свойство float:left; или float:right; то display будет иметь значение block!

Но я не соглашусь!" - Автор не согласен, а я показал один пример, где так и есть. Если первые две фразы не представляют собой суть вопроса, то вообще весь вопрос надо закрывать, потому что непонятна его суть.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Думаю все же мы тут не из-за кармы, а в целях установления истины.

Comment: Вот я и пытаюсь установить истину.  И мой ответ - единственный здесь пример по сути - display становится block, если применили float: left;

Comment: Дак автор об этом сам сказал. Простите, но даже у @Grundy больше конструктива в комментриях.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Пока что меньше всего конструктива в ваших комментариях

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov пожалуйста, я всего лишь ответил вам взаимностью

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56438/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-andrey-fedorov).

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ну и ладно. Но как же истина?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov вот вы и устанавливайте. Дайте лучший ответ, вместо того, чтобы заниматься троллингом в комментариях.

Comment: @KAGGDesign очень жаль, что вы так это восприняли.